# Can I use fiber channel drives with normal server for home labs

Tags: hard-drive, nas, webserver, fiber

I am planning to buy [this](http://www.ebay.com.au/itm/NetApp-Disk-Shelf-MK2-DS14-Hard-Drive-Array-14x-300GB-10K-FC-Hard-Drives-8-S19-/281030629454?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_15&hash=item416ebb184e)

But I am not sure if I can attach it to my IBM server x3650 M2 to use as storage / backup of VMS. I don't know much about these fiber drives.

Can anyone please help me on this?

Comment: You're running [VMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenVMS)? Cool! :)  Anyhow, what has you research told you so far?  Where are you getting stuck exactly? Do you have a compatible controller installed?

Comment: @techie007 ha ha sorry i means vm's virtual machines :). WHat u mean by compatible controllers. what are they and how can i chck that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need at minimum a Fiber channel card for your server, and SFPs for the thing you are buying which has empty SFP slots, and some fiber (or copper if you get copper SFPs, but fiber can often be cheaper and also has much more flexible length options.) You will probably need SFPs for the card you put in the server as well, unless it happens to come with them.

Used, these parts can be quite reasonable if 4Gb/sec fiber channel will do what you want. Lots of surplus available at that speed class. Oddly, you can often find single-mode FiberChannel SFPs cheaper than multimode, but that's just a matter of what you can find shopping at any given point in time, and making sure that the SFPs and fiber you get are all the same so that they will work together. The 10km single-mode SFPs work fine at 5 meters as well, so no need to assume that short-haul means you can't use single-mode - but don't try that with 80km units (though they won't be the cheap ones anyway.)